# C++ 11 regex: checking if string starts with regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++11, boost-regex

I am using C++ 11's `<regex>` support, and would like to check whether the beginning of a string matches a regular expression. [I can switch to Boost if that helps, but my impression is that they're basically the same.]

Obviously if I have control of the actual textual representation of the expression, I can just stick a `^` at the beginning of it as an anchor.

However, what if I just have a `regex` (or `basic_regex`) object? Can I modify the regular expression it represents to add the anchor? Or do I have to use `regex_search`, get the result, and check whether it starts at position 0?

Comment: Many ordinary string can be consider as regex. `"abc"` is also a regex, but only match the exact string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could add the `std::regex_constants::match_continuous` flag when using `regex_search`, for example, the following prints "1" and "0":

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::regex rx ("\\d+");

    printf("%d\n", std::regex_search("12345abc1234", rx,
                                     std::regex_constants::match_continuous));
    printf("%d\n", std::regex_search("abc12345", rx,
                                     std::regex_constants::match_continuous));
    return 0;
}
```

---

The flag means (C++11 §28.5.2/1 = Table 139):

> The expression shall only match a sub-sequence that begins at `first`.

Comment: That's an, um, interesting name for the flag, but that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a bundle